# watch a template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have a full template

I would like to put a watch on this tempalte, in order to call a function in the controller any time something is clicked inside that template.

I know I have to use a watch (I believe I do) but I don't understand how to to the connection between the full template and the watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this just add the `ng-click` directive to your parent element so that every click inside that element evaluates the expression inside the `ng-click` attribute:

```
<div class="parent" ng-click="callFunction()">
 <div>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

If you want some clicks inside the parent element to not trigger the parent `ng-click` you can add `$event.stopPropagation()` to stop event propagation:

```
<div class="parent" ng-click="callFunction()">
 <div>Clicking here will call parent callFunction()</div>
 <div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();callAnotherFunction();">
  Clicking here won´t call parent´s callFunction()
 </div>
</div>
```